# Page redirects to /users after /users/sign_up failure using Devise (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

With my default devise configuration, when sign up fails due to some reason (e.g. email already taken), it redirects to /users instead of the same path /users/sign_up. Any leads into how I can debug this?
I tried to override after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource) in my application controller, but it is not getting called.

My application is using devise 3.2.4 on rails 3.2.13

Comment: Perpahs try generating the controllers so you can take a look at what it's doing. 
`rails generate devise:controllers user`

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: I'm having the exact same question.

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel I have tried `rails generate devise:controllers user`. It doesn't help. Generated files just provide all commented code.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43228858/5383834). It works for me.