# Why does Devise redirect sign_up error to a different page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created new rails project with just a generated controller for a home page to test this.

Me devise model is `User`, so the signup page is `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up`.

If I trigger an error, for example, submitting the form without giving password, I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/users`.

How can I stay on `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` after making errors?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930614/rails-devise-redirecting-to-users-instead-of-users-sign-up-on-failed-regis) and [the only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42930725/5383834) suggests using `redirect_to :back` in the controller.

The problem is I am not overriding the controller. If overriding is the only way to solve, please explain how it should be.

This is my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "home#index"
  get 'home/index'
  devise_for :users
end
```

[Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) is the source code of `Devise::RegistrationsController`. How should I override `new` or `create` to achieve what I need?

Comment: it is default behaviour of rails. when any error occurs it will again render the form. so all the values of form remain same. if you use redirect back and  any error occur it will give new form . all the values of form will be destroy

Comment: It renders the form again, that's correct. The problem is url changes from `/users/sign_up` to `/users`.

Comment: can you post up the routes (and controller/action) specific to devise within your app?

Comment: @Wit because it is route for for create user like POST '/users' , so it routes to "/users" as post method but error occurs so it will only render the form again . because there is no view for create method. got it ?

Comment: @BigJ Ok I will. But actually I didn't modify anything.

Comment: @Vishal Ok. I think I get what you try to explain. Is there any workaround I can do?

Comment: @Wit You can override devise registration controller and use redirect_to back when error occur. but you will lost your whole form values and user have to again feel values. and one more thing. the errors won't show to user in redirect_to back

Comment: @Wit you could just add the ClientSideValidations gem: https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations - this way the form doesn't submit if you don't enter a password, it just prompts with an error message on the same form that you have to fill in that field. Also - any fields already filled will stay that way..

Comment: @BigJ That's a good idea but I have reCAPTCHA and I don't think they can work together.

Comment: @BigJ There lots of better plugins available for client side validation like jquery validate. but we should add server side validation. because any developer can change the value from inspect element . and submit forms. `server side validations are must`

Comment: @Vishal I wasn't suggesting that server side validations should not be used, the suggestion was so that the form would not be submitted if it wasn't valid to avoid redirection.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you don't do this. The default behavior of Rails applications (following the route naming conventions) is that way you described. But, if you really need to to this, here's how.

First, go to your `routes.rb`and:

```
devise_scope :user do
    post 'users/sign_up', to: 'devise/registrations#create'
end
```

**EDIT**

Then, generate the devise views so you can override the default behavior of the forms.

```
rails g devise:views
```

Then, open your `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html` file and edit the `form_for` line so it looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: users_sign_up_path) do |f| %>
```